# How to fix java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when generating pdf document?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, apache-fop

My system throws exception: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", when it processed a huge file. I realized that StringWriter.toString() cause the double size in heap, so it could cause the issue. How can I optimize block of following code to avoid Out Of Memory.

```
public byte[] generateFromFo(final StringWriter foString) {
        try {
            StringReader foReader = new StringReader(foString.toString());
            ByteArrayOutputStream pdfWriter = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, fopFactory.newFOUserAgent(),pdfWriter);
            TRANSFORMER_FACTORY.newTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(foReader), new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler()));
            LOG.debug("Completed rendering PDF output!");
            return pdfWriter.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while generating PDF from FO",e);
            throw new AuditReportExportServiceException(AuditErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR,"Could not generate PDF from XSL-FO");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an InputStream of bytes may reduce the memory for foString by upto a factor 2 (char = 2 bytes).

A ByteArrayOutputStream resizes during its filling, so adding an estimated need speeds things up, and might prevent a resizing too much.

```
        InputStream foReader = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                foString.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        foString.close();
        final int initialCapacity = 160 * 1024;
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfWriter = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialCapacity);
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, fopFactory.newFOUserAgent(),
            pdfWriter);
        TRANSFORMER_FACTORY.newTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(foReader),
            new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler()));
```

The best would be to change the API:

```
public void generateFromFo(final String foString, OutputStream pdfOut) { ... }
```

This might make the `ByteArrayOutputStream` superfluous, and you might immediately stream to a file, URL, or whatever.

The document itself and the generated PDF also has issues:

- image sizes (but remember the higher resolution of prints)
- some images can be nicely vectorized
- repeated images like in a page header, should be stored once
- fonts should ideally be the standard fonts, second best embedded subsets (of used chars)
- XML might be suboptimal, very repetitive

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, you have two main options:

1. Increase the memory available to your process. The `-Xmx` option to Java will set this config. You could pass e.g. `-Xmx8G` to ask for 8GB of memory on a 64 bit system, if you have that much. Docs are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard
2. Change your code to "stream" the data through in smaller chunks, rather than trying to assemble the whole file into a `byte[]` in memory, as you have done here. You could change the output of your transformer to a `FileOutputStream` rather than a  `ByteArrayOutputStream` and return a `File` rather than a `byte[]` in the code shown? Or, depending on what you do with the output of this method, you could return an `InputStream` and allow the consumer to receive the file data in a streaming fashion?

   You may also need to change things so that the input to this method is consumed in a streaming fashion. How to do that depends on the details of how `StringWriter foString` was created. You may need to "pipe" an `OutputStream` into an `InputStream` to make this work, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html

1 is simpler. 2 is probably better here.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Option 1 is simple but it is my last option because I don't want to waste memory for bad code. 
I will try your second suggestion. 
Thanks

Comment: OK, good luck. Depending on the context, 1 may be a better option. Maybe think of it as "using" the memory, rather than "wasting" it. It depends on your priorities. :-)